# How can I take the first and last item of string in sql query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a log table of staff entrance and exit dates and time like below;

- 11/12/2007 12:23,11/12/2007 21:22,...,11/12/2007 22:24
- 12/12/2007 09:11,12/12/2007 11:34,...,12/12/2007 17:15
- ...continues

Number of items are different and all entries are in daily based. Minimum entry will be 2 because of entrance and exit logs.

I want to take only the start and end date from the logs.  Please help me about the T-SQL query...

Comment: please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Sqlserver 2005 or above, using REVERSE function many times is detrimental to performance, below code is more efficient.

Assume that column name ise logdata and table name is logTable

```
SELECT 
   SUBSTRING(logdata, 0, CHARINDEX(',', logdata)) AS FirstItem,
   SUBSTRING(logdata, (LEN(logdata) - CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(logdata))+2), LEN(logdata)) AS LastItem
FROM logTable
```

You can check the exact solution in this link http://rextester.com/TRGHL10059

Answer (score 4):

Another Simple Solution of your problem use Left and Right Function

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)='11/12/2007 12:23,11/12/2007 21:22,11/12/2007 22:24'
```

SELECT LEFT(@str, CHARINDEX(',',@str) -1),
Right(@str, CHARINDEX(',', Reverse(@str)) -1)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, due to the fact that all of the datetime stamps are a fixed number of characters, you could be able to use something as simple as the LEFT & RIGHT functions... (no real need to over complicate things)...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MovementLog', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #MovementLog;

CREATE TABLE #MovementLog (
    LogDate DATE NOT NULL,
    ClockTimeString VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL 
    ); 

INSERT #MovementLog (LogDate, ClockTimeString) VALUES 
    ('2007-12-11', '11/12/2007 12:23,11/12/2007 21:22,11/12/2007 22:24'),
    ('2007-12-12', '12/12/2007 09:11,12/12/2007 11:34,12/12/2007 17:15');

--==============================================================================

SELECT 
    ml.LogDate,
    BegDTStamp = LEFT(ml.ClockTimeString, 16),
    EndDTStamp = RIGHT(ml.ClockTimeString, 16)
FROM 
    #MovementLog ml;
```

results...

```
LogDate    BegDTStamp       EndDTStamp
---------- ---------------- ----------------
2007-12-11 11/12/2007 12:23 11/12/2007 22:24
2007-12-12 12/12/2007 09:11 12/12/2007 17:15
```